# Swipe last slide using swiper, but don't loop to first

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I'm currently using iDangerous's Swiper plugin for jQuery. When it gets to the last slide, the only options seem to be to loop to the first slide (loop:true) or don't allow any swiping (loop:false). Does anyone know how to force it to allow swiping of the last slide off the screen, while not showing another slide?

Documentation:
http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VXWXU89VhBc

Maybe I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Put a "blank" (`opacity: 0` / `visibility:hidden`) slide at the end so you have the appearance of the last slide disappearing.